# How to supply a key on the command line that's not Base 64 encoded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Regarding the AWS S3 tool "sync" and a "customer-provided encryption key", it says [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html),

> --sse-c-key (string) The customer-provided encryption key to use to server-side encrypt the object in S3. If you provide this value,
>   --sse-c be specfied as well. The key provided should not be base64 encoded.

How does one supply a key on the command line that is not base64 encoded?

If the key is not base64 encoded, then surely some of the key's bytes would not be expressible as characters?

Comment: `$ echo -e "\x75\x73\x65\x20\x68\x65\x78\x20\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65\x73\x3F"`

Comment: Why didn't you put that as an answer?

Comment: Honestly? Because I was guessing. :)  I've never tried SSE-C with aws-cli.  Does it work for you?

Comment: Using your key, its says, "The secret key was invalid for the specified algorthm".

Comment: My "key" isn't a key.  It decodes to "use hex escapes?"

Comment: Whatever it is, this doesn't work with or without quotes... --sse-c-key \x75\x73\x65\x20\x68\x65\x78\x20\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65\x73\x3F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first glance, this seems like a HUGE oversight in the aws cli. However, buried deep in the CLI documentation is a blurb on how to provide binary data on the command line.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html
(updated link per @Chris's comment)

This did in fact work for me...

`aws s3 cp --sse-c AES256 --sse-c-key fileb://key.bin large_file s3://mybucket/`

The `fileb://` part is the answer

Comment: As of Nov 2017, this doesn't work. I get "Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter input, value: b"\xefT\xa4k...", type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>"

Comment: @amonroejj What does your file look like? It needs to be actual binary data, not encoded binary.

Comment: I used the random bytes feature on random.org. Per the error message, it's only considering an instance of str as valid.

Comment: Did you download the bytes to a file from random.org or did you copy and paste them? It looks like you are using a string representation of binary instead of actual binary itself. 

On linux or osx, you can run this to get 32 bytes or random binary:

`cat /dev/random | head -c 32 > key.bin`

That is how I generated the random binary in my example above and it worked fine.

Comment: File. You can see this in my pasted error; the first byte (EF) is not a traditional ASCII chararacter.

Comment: I also see the error amonroejj saw.  So it seems the command line does not permit a binary key only a string key (32 characters)

Comment: Is this the better link @Jeff? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html The link in the answer now just shows a key pair example.