# Amazon S3 SSE-C encryption of file already on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have an application running since many time that uploads files (images) on S3 storage.

Now I've been requested to update this application and upload file using SSE-C encryption (Server Side Encryption with Customer provided key). So I did it.

I'm also able to upload SSE-C encrypted files using aws cli.

What I need now, and here is my question, is to find a way to apply SSE-C encryption to earlier files already on S3 without SSE-C encryption.

Could someone explain me if and how this can be accomplished or point me to some doc or support page in order to find a solution?

One (maybe inefficient) way I found is doing the following for each file:

1. copy filename to filename.encrypted applying the SSE-C encryption
2. move filename.encrypted to filename

Is this the only way to do it or there is a better one?

NOTES:

- Since I have many many files I obviously excluded the option to download the file and then upload again with SSE-C encryption because it'll be too slow and too expensive.
- A solution that let apply the SSE-C without data transfert from and back to S3 is the one I'm looking for.

Thank you very much for any feedback on this.

Comment: Side-note: There is no 'move' or 'rename' command in Amazon S3. You would need to copy an object, then delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply encryption to already-existing objects by simply copying the object on top of itself:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/foo.txt s3://bucket/foo.txt --sse-c --sse-c-key fileb://key.bin
```

This works as long as something (eg the encryption) is changing.

I got the `--sse-c` syntax from: [How to supply a key on the command line that's not Base 64 encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46225537/174777)

Comment: Hi @john-rotenstein, thank you for feedback.

I had to use aws s3api commands to accomplish this: aws s3api copy-object --copy-source bucketname/file.jpg --key file.jpg --bucket bucketname --sse-customer-algorithm AES256 --sse-customer-key fileb:///absolute/path/to/key/file

Using aws s3 commands ends up in the following error:
aws s3 cp --sse-c --sse-c-key fileb:///absolute/path/to/key/file s3://bucketname/file.jpg s3://bucketname/file.jpg

Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter input, value: b'...[somebyteshere]...', type: <class 'bytes'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Comment: Double check that you can decrypt the file. This issue that you had is caused by using a binary file instead of a file with 32 hex characters. I think that this is a real problem in that AWS does not clearly document what a key is (binary data, 32 hex characters, etc. in every place it is used) Using one format where another is expected will result in encrypting with a different key than you think you are using. Later you will be pulling your hair out trying to figure out why decryption is failing.